# repeater mouseover event in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, repeater

I have a Cart Icon on top left corer of my page, I am using a template, it has a feature the on mouse over on that icon it displays a list of items ordered. I want to diplay list of items order in same box. I am using cookies , I checked via breakpont I am getting all values in the cookies.
Heres the aspx code for the box:

```
<div class="navbar-ecommerce pull-right"><a href="#" class="link-cart"><i class="icon-cart"></i> <span class="badge">39</span></a>
            <div class="cart-list">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <%--<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater2_ItemCommand" >--%>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound" >
                            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>

                        <a href="#" class="cart-img"><img alt="" src=" images/ecommerce/products/hoodie_4_front-150x150.jpg"></a>
                        <p><a href="#"><%#Eval("ItemName") %></a> <span class="quantity">1 x <span class="amount"><%#Eval("Rate") %></span></span></p>
                        <a class="remove fa fa-times" href="#"></a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                    </li>


                </ul>

               <div class="total"><strong>Subtotal:</strong> <span class="amount">$ 2,380.00</span></div>

                <div class="buttons">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-left">View Cart</a> 
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Checkout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I was not sure which event to take so i took `OnItemCommand` and `OnItemBound` none of them triggers the code behind.
My Code behind:

```
protected void Repeater2_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("ItemName"), new DataColumn("Category"), new DataColumn("Rate") });

        if (Request.Cookies["cart"] != null)
        {
            cookies = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["cart"].Value);
            string[] arrorder = cookies.Split('|');
            for (int i = 0; i < arrorder.Length; i++)
            {
                order = Convert.ToString(arrorder[i].ToString());
                string[] arritem = order.Split(',');
                for (int j = 0; j < arritem.Length; j++)
                {
                    fields[j] = arritem[j].ToString();
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(fields[0].ToString(), fields[1].ToString(), fields[2].ToString());
            }
        }
        Repeater2.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
    }
```

Same set of code is written for `protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)`

So please help which event to fire to get the list diplayed in the box. If there is any alternate way do let me too. Thanks

Comment: `ItemCommand` is used when you have `button` in your repeater, and `ItemDataBound` when item is added (bound) to repeater. You'll have to use javascript/jquery to achieve this.

Comment: oh didnt knew, great info, will try

Comment: @Nino any idea how to procede with javascript?